# Browser response size limit

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am calling my cross domain web-service through a getJson() call from jQuery.  As my response object size is pretty big, i have used the maximum JSon size for my web-service. I have checked getJson() is giving proper response object. But still my callback function is not called. Firebug is saying that it's(firefox) response size is exceeded.

Can anybody tell me whats the maximum browser response size limit that the standard browser e.g (firefox, ie) handle and how to deal with the problem?

Here is the code snippet for the same.

```
 //Wrapper call to the actual getJson call
 function getResponse() {
    var localService = new getServiceProxy("SearchData.asmx");
    localService.invoke("Search", "", "successcall");
 }

 //getJson call
 function getServiceProxy(serviceUrl) {
     var _I = this;
     this.serviceUrl = serviceUrl;

     // *** Call a wrapped object
     this.invoke = function(method, data, callback, error) {

         if (data == "") {
             var url = _I.serviceUrl + "/" + method + "?output=json&callback=?";
         }
         else {
             url = _I.serviceUrl + "/" + method + "?" + data + "&output=json&callback=?";
         }
         $.getJSON(url, function(arg) {       
             var evalstr = callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(arg) + ");";
             eval(evalstr);
         });
     }
 }

 //success callback function
 function successcall(multiSearchResponse) {
     //use the response.
 }
```

any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks Subrat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive been through this once in a project, and what I recall was that IE has a limit of 2083 characters for both POST and GET requests. FF has a larger limit, but not limitless.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427

Comment: POST should have no length limit, otherwise file uploads would be impossible. GET, on the other hand, does have a ~2k limit.

Comment: The support article that you linked to, says it right in the title: "Maximum **URL length** is 2,083 characters in Internet Explorer". @subrat asked about the maximum **response size**.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that looks kind of weird is the callback function:

```
 $.getJSON(url, function(arg) {       
     var evalstr = callback + "(" + JSON.stringify(arg) + ");";
     eval(evalstr);
 });
```

Since you are using JSONP (due to the request being cross-domain) the responding service should return a JavaScript like:

```
jQueryGeneratedUniqueCallbackName12345({my: 'data', foo: 'bar'});
```

So the **arg** argument is the actual JavaScript object. You should not need to stringify and then eval it. Simply use it as it is, i.e.:

```
 $.getJSON(url, function(data) {       
     console.log(data.foo);
 });
```

Quite a while ago I posted about the [inner workings of JSONP](http://www.stpe.se/2008/10/cross-site-data-retrieval-using-jsonp/) on my blog if you are interested in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want your `$.getJSON` part look as follows:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(arg) {       
    callback.apply(null, JSON.stringify(arg));
});

// Or more simply

$.getJSON(url, function(arg) {       
    callback(JSON.stringify(arg));
});
```

Some more info about `apply`: [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

---

**UPDATE:** Before that you could also change the `getResponse` function to:

```
function getResponse() {
    var localService = new getServiceProxy("SearchData.asmx");
    localService.invoke('Search', '', successcall);
}
```