# Not enough storage is available to complete this operation in IE11

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have one problem in my angularJS application. I am doing one api call to server and that api returns me 12MB Json data. It works fine in Chrome but in IE11 it is throwing an error 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation' continuously.

I am stuck here and can't go ahead.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Response size has a limit.Check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814913/browser-response-size-limit

Comment: I understand response has a limit,but its my business requirement. any solution or alternative??

Comment: I understand that but it is a pertinent issue. Check this reply from microsoft regarding the same issue : https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1053110

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and here is something that map help ... check the Browsing History in IE to see if it has enough space to hold what is being returned as the json.  (Internet Options -> General Tab -> and in the Browsing History section, click on the Settings button and verify the Disk space to use.